# What is the best way to stop a loop from outside it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, break

I have a python script that prints a spinner. This spinner, hopefully, will last until stopped.

```py
spinnerFrames = [
    "/",
    "-",
    "\\",
    "|",
]

def spinner():
  i = 0
  while True:
    clearScreen() #function to clear the screen
    print(spinnerFrames[i])
    i = i + 1
    if (i == 3):
      i = 0
    sleep(0.15)

spinner()
sleep(3)
# break out here
print("Done!")
```

I know you can do `sys.stdout.write()` and then only delete that line, but that's beside the point.

I can't figure out the best way to stop the loop and exit the function. (To continue on in my code)I'd like to be able to break from the loop down where you call it, as I hope to make this a Pip package.

This, I assume is possible, though I don't know how to do it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can't. When you do `sleep(0.15)`, the interpreter sleeps inside your `spinner()` function. You should check inside the loop if a condition is satisfied (e.g. whatever operation you were waiting on is finished), and then break if it is.

Comment: Your code wont ever reach the "break out here" part until the loop finishes and the function returns in your current set up, if you want to run the spinner as another process while the rest of your code executes then you need to look at multi processing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run it asynchronously, like how the multiprocessing library allows you to do. When you create a separate thread, you'll be left with a handle on it that you can use to kill it when you want it to stop.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep
spinnerFrames = [
    "/",
    "-",
    "\\",
    "|",
]
def spinner():
  i = 0
  while True:
    print(spinnerFrames[i], end='\r')
    i = i + 1
    if (i == 3):
      i = 0
    sleep(0.15)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
  p = Process(target=spinner)
  p.start()
  sleep(3)
  p.terminate()
  print("Done!")
```

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. I would suggest adding it as a comment to the question, or coding up an example to explain as an answer.

Comment: How do you run it asynchronously? I could do that.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm new to this whole thing, so I'm still getting used to what answers are supposed to look like.

Comment: @RevelCarlbergWest This is a good starting point for async with python- https://medium.com/velotio-perspectives/an-introduction-to-asynchronous-programming-in-python-af0189a88bbb

Comment: @superbrain No for sure they dont need to include code.

Comment: @LionelFoxcroft Thanks, your answer was great. If you want, you can put a link to python async or some code. Don't feel weird, you helped!

Comment: @RevelCarlbergWest I've added some code now! Thanks for all your positivity :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a reference implementation from one of my projects. It prints dots instead of a spinner, but it is trivial to change:

```
import threading
import time

def indicate_wait(func): 
    active = threading.Lock() 
     
    def dot_printer(): 
        while active.locked(): 
            print('.', end='', flush=True) 
            time.sleep(1) 
             
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs): 
        t = threading.Thread(target=dot_printer) 
        active.acquire() 
        t.start() 
        res = func(*args, **kwargs) 
        active.release() 
        return res 
     
    return wrapper
```

Example:

```
@indicate_wait 
def test(): 
    time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

record when it started, then break loop if current time - start time >
duration.

```
import time
spinnerFrames = [
    "/",
    "-",
    "\\",
    "|",
]

def spinner():
  i = 0
  startTime = time.time()# record starting time
  duration = 3
  while True:
    clearScreen() #function to clear the screen
    print(spinnerFrames[i])
    i = i + 1
    if (i == 3):
      i = 0
    if time.time() - startTime > duration:
      break
    sleep(0.15)

spinner()
print("Done!")
```

Comment: I could do that, but I only want to break out when I want to, not by duration. The point s for the spinner to last until some loading is done not a set amount of time.